# get the record value from XML Store in EXT js

Tags: extjs, xmlstore

I am ExtJS for GUI development. I am using XML Store for retrieving the data from server.

My XML looks like this.

```
<meta>
 <entry>x</entry>
 <entry>Y</entry>
</meta>
<data>
  <value>100</value>
  <value>500</value>
 </data>
```

Where X=100 and Y=500

How do i retrieve the data and value from this using XMLStore?

Comment: Are you sure this is the XML structure you want ?
The correlation between the metadata and the data is flaky ...
How does it look with multiple data records ? (If there aren't multiple entries the need for a data store is questionable)

Comment: I am actually getting the XML data from another tool. I can't change the XML format.Also the number of field "entry" and field "value" are fixed.They are equal in number always.

Comment: So why do you need it in a data store ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a store with 2 fields: "entry" and "value", and you can have 2 pairs like this as in your example or more than 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the XML structure is not really suitable for what the XML Store/Reader expect, I  suggest you parse the XML yourself into a more standard format and then load the data to a JsonStore for example.

Parsing code: (wrote it off the top of my head, so might need some adjustments ...)

```
var data = [];
var q = Ext.DomQuery;
var entries = q.select('meta > entry', theXML);
var values = q.select('data > value', theXML);
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
    var recordData = {
        entry: entries[i].firstChild.nodeValue,
        value: values[i].firstChild.nodeValue
    }
    data.push(recordData);
}
```

Hope it will be useful to you ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is the "theXML" refers to the location of the XML file? In my case, it is exported through a REST API. Is it possible to use the URI in this code instead of the XML file path?

Comment: The "theXML" is the XML DOM document (or the document root node object). You can get one by doing an AJAX call to your REST API URL and accessing *response.responseXML* on the success callback